# Finding the key of the last searchable document in SOLR 4

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using SOLR 4 for an application, where I need to search the index soon after inserting records.

I'm using the solrj code below to get the last ID in the index. However, I noticed that the last id I see when I execute a query through the solr web admin is often lagging behind this. And that my searches are not including all documents up until the last ID I get from the code snippet below. Is this because of delays in hard commits? I don't need to switch to soft commits yet. I just want to make sure that I get the ID of the last searchable document. Is this possible to do?

```
     SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
     query.set("qt","/select");
     query.setQuery( "*:*" );
     query.setFields("id");
     query.set("rows","1");
     query.set("sort","id desc");

     QueryResponse rsp = m_Server.query( query );
     SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
     SolrDocument doc = docs.get(0);
     long id = (Long) doc.getFieldValue("id");
```

UPDATED:
I'm committing documents in solrj in the following way:

```
    m_Server = new HttpSolrServer(m_Url);
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField( "id", id);
    doc.addField( "text", text);
    m_Server.add(doc);      
    m_Server.commit();
```

Is it possible that some fields (id, in this case) becomes searchable before others (the text, in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

How are you committing the index? 
You should use commit with `waitSearcher=true` and `waitFlush=true` so that it blocks until the new searcher becomes available for querying with Solrj commit.

Else, there would be some delay between the Commits and the New Searcher are opened with the New index being available. Till then the searches would be executed by the Old searches which would have old data.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post with how I'm committing to the index.

Comment: Can I set the waitSearcher and waitFlush option in solrj? Or do I need to restart the solr with new config settings?

Comment: According to this page: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages waitSearch is true by default, and waitFlush "has no affect".

Comment: yup ... both default to true. SO am not sure if is the creation of new searcher or cache warming which is causing the delay.